# Can you get window.location from firebase functions (with handlebars, amp and express)

Tags: handlebars.js, frontend, google-cloud-functions

I have a couple of handlebar views with express and firebase functions.
Then I am loading the index view inside of another page (using a XMLHttpRequest):

```
xhttp.open("get", "`firebase-functions-link`/api/index", true);
```

then I have an express router witch sends me to the index controller

```
...
router.route('/index').get(indexCtrl.render);
...
```

Then in my controller I render my index.handlebars function

```
template = (device === 'mobile' ? 'm-index' : 'index'), 
...
res.render(template, {...props, layout: false });
```

I am trying to get something like windows.location or document.location inside that function, but I can't seem to find any way. I need that so I can store the initial site, because the interaction continues on the function domain, but I want the user to be able to return to the initial site.

So on short, when someone does a request from a site to my functions I want to get the full link from the page that did the request.

While I do know that the easiest way to accomplish this would be to send the data from the page that calls my function, there are several pages from where my function can be called. So I'd rather do it in one place is possible (without the need to update each page that is using and will use the function).

Comment: well, NodeJS is running on the server-side not at the front.
Alot of people make this mistake.

Comment: I understand that, but I was thinking maybe I can get that from some parameters send with the request (the req object doesn't seem to have it but I was thinking maybe there is some function or another object you can pass to get it) or to get it in the handlebar, since the index.hadlebars is loaded in the index.html. So if I could call windows.location in index.handlebars it would be exactly what I need, but I don't have access to window or document objects in index.handlebars .

Comment: Well, why not send some parameter to the HBS page and use window.location when ever you need?

Comment: Because the initial page is like a theme. And the HBS will be called by different themes. So I would like, if possible, to do this automatically in the HBS, rather than changing every index.html to send parameter.